# Freestyle lines as an independent render pass

Tags: render-passes

In 2.7x series I could select Freestyle lines into its own render pass. In 2.80RC2 I cannot find such an option. Is it not implemented yet or I am missing it?

Answer (score 3):

As of Blender 2.83, freestyle can be separated into its own render pass by checking the **As Render Pass** checkbox in the freestyle settings.

[image: as render pass checkbox]

Answer (score 2):

The option isn't available in Eevee but is still available in Cycles. You need to use the Filter panel in the Render Layers properties and disable the elements (eg, Surfaces) that you don't want to appear in the render :

[image: freestyle filter]